# Upgraded this morning, now stuck with no X login

Tags: 14.04, updates, login-screen

So... have had a fully functional Ubuntu 14.04 system installed dual-boot with Win 7 on my Lenovo T530 ThinkPad for months... 12.10, 13.04 & 13.10 before that. Some hiccups with 14.04, but overall a stable system.

Until this morning.

The regular system update was grumbling about wine-compholio again as per usual. So I opened a terminal and manually ran "sudo apt-get update" followed by "sudo apt-get upgrade" with no problems. Then I rebooted the system, and now the gui startup hangs @ the "ubuntu" with the five status dots indefinitely.

I can get to a terminal via Ctrl+Alt+F1, and back via Ctrl+Alt+F7, but no idea where to go from there.

I can reboot into Win7 just fine, FWIW.

I really need to get to some work I have on my Linux desktop ASAP so any help would be greatly appreciated.

As per request,  the last few lines from the boot log accessed via F12 during boot splash (bear with me;  I am having to type these in by gand using my tablet):

```
* Stopping cold plug devices     [ OK ]
Starting VirtualBox kernel modules * Stopping log initial device creation     [ OK ]
* Starting save udev log and update rules     [ OK ]
* Stopping save udev log and update rules     [ OK ]
* Starting enable remaining boot-time encrypted block devices     [ OK ]
```

Comment: Hitting F12 during the boosplash should reveal possible error messages behind it. if there are any, add them to your question, please.

Comment: @the_Seppi, updated original question

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get install --reinstall xubuntu-desktop`

Comment: Went thru all the Advanced options... figures the last one I tried, which was the regular version of the previous kernel release (3.13-24, if memory serves) did the trick.  Did something change with the new kernel release that doesn't play nice with nVidia cards?

Answer (score 0):

Almost identical issue:
Lenovo W530 laptop setup for dual boot Windows 7 / Ubuntu 14.04
Things have worked great since a fresh install about 3 weeks ago and several reboots.

Then, Ubuntu froze last night on power up.

Windows 7 boots fine.

But, Ubuntu boot up hangs with the error:

Starting enable remaining boot-time encrypted block devices [OK]

Nothing works after that.
But CTL ALT Delete will shut the system off gracefully

Even the initial boot loaded hangs - the count down clock does not show at the bottom of the screen and I have to manually select Ubuntu or Windows to boot up.

Then I fixed it (for me anyway).

I figured "What's changed"
I have 2 USB hard drives that are (effectively) permanently attached to the docking station. At some point in the past three weeks, I made 2 entries in the /etc/fstab to mount them every reboot.

Last night, I pulled the system out of the docking station.
And, the system would not boot into Ubuntu.

As a test, I plugged both USB drives directly into laptop and it booted up normally.

I edited the /etc/fstab and commented out the two USB drives.

From that point on, the laptop booted normally with or without the USB drives attached and in or out of the docking station.

Now, the USB drives show up in the menu tray on the left instead of a drive path. 
But, I guess if the consequences of forgetting to edit the /etc/fstab file when I remove the laptop from the docking station is a lockup, then I will live with them being in the menu tray.

Hope this helps you.